The Diophantine equation $45x^4-42x^2y^2+5y^4=8$
Solving the recent combinatorial rectangle packing problem
by Elliott Price, I encountered the Diophantine equation $$45x^4-42x^2y^2+5y^4=8.$$
It it easy to see that the equation has the solution $x=y=1$, and I guess that it has no other positive integer solutions. Anyway, to find all such solutions of the equation can be an easy task for a specialist, which I am not, so I decided to ask MSE community for help. Thanks.
My try. I expect that it is easy to show that the equation has only finitely many integer solutions,
using either Thue–Siegel–Roth theorem
or the Siegel(?) theorem
Concerning the elementary tools, it is easy to check that both $x$ and $y$ are odd.
But the substitution $x=2u+1$ and $y=2v+1$ provides us the Diophantine equation
$$45u^4+90u^3-42u^2v^2-42u^2v+57u^2-42uv^2-42uv+12u+5v^4+10v^3-3v^2-8v=0$$
which does not look more easy to solve than the initial one.
Nevertheless, we can note that $v\not\equiv 1\pmod 3$.

Lots of relevant material in Mordell, Diophantine Equations. Meanwhile, it is fairly easy to describe all integer solutions to $45 r^2 - 42 rs + 5 s^2 = 8$

@WillJagy Yes, Mordell is a cool guy, so I expect he wrote a great book about Diophantine equations.
But now we are interested in the only one of them, for the application sake.
Yes, I guess we can provide a sequence of all integer solutions of the respective quadratic equation,
like that for Pell's equation.
But the problem is to sieve from them the perfect squares.

I'm not sure if this helps, but we see that $\frac{3y^4+5}{2}$ has to be a square number since $15x^2=7y^2\pm 2\sqrt{2(3y^4+5)}$.

There is at least one guy on the site who is quick to answer (or comment) similar questions with elliptic-curve related software.  The user I have in mind is  tomita, I'll see what I can do. Hmmm, seems innactive for a few weeks. In the U.S.  this is college graduation time, may be busy

@mathlove That condition seems to be strong indeed by itself, did some quick search of integer solutions $3y^4+5=2z^2$ and I couldn't find other solution than $y=\pm 1$.

Here is a practical answer, for the theory or algorithm description check the links, or someone else can elaborate if needed.
This is a Thue equation and there are efficient algorithms for finding all solutions. One such cited is On the practical solution of the Thue equation by Tzanakis and de Weger.
In practice we can use for example function thue in PARI/GP:
thue(thueinit(45*x^4 - 42*x^2 + 5),8)

with output:
[[-1, -1], [-1, 1], [1, -1], [1, 1]]

So all integral solutions are given by $(x,y)=(\pm 1, \pm 1)$.
